# How can I have a different package name for debug and release in a library module?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

**Short question**:

How can I change the package name for **debug** or **release** build type in a library module?

**Context**:

In an Android project with MVP + Clean architecture, we have the repository pattern in a library module. We want to include Firebase on that library with two environments (development and production).

I already created the project in Firebase (`com.example.com` and `com.example.com.dev`) and then downloaded the respective `google-services.json` to src/main and src/debug folders.

Gradle **google-services** plugin validates the module package name with the client ID defined in the **google-services.json**, but Android restrict to change the `applicationId` in a library (I can't find the technical reason why)

**Things that I tried**:

- Have two AndroidManifest.xml with different package property. `com.example.com` in the src/main and `com.example.com.dev` in src/debug/ but the second one it is just ignored
- Set `manifest.srcFile` in Gradle sourceSets. The file is in the list when I run `./gradlew sourceSets` but the package name doesn't change
- Two different flavors in the library module and set different manifests for each one. The package anyway doesn't change.

At this moment I have just two suitable solutions: 
1. Keep the Firebase setup and implementation in the app module outside of the repository.
2. Have only one environment for Firebase.

Thanks a lot for any help or advice.

***EDIT***:

Consider that I need to modify the package in a module (library), not in the app. For some weird reason Gradle shows this error when I try to use `applicationIdSuffix` or `applicationId` in a module:

ERROR: Library projects cannot set applicationIdSuffix.

Comment: I've not been able to set this in an automated fashion either, but the technical reason why suffix can't be used is explained here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/OF-kwxX7Cuc/6cOuvS4FEAIJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time investigating and trying different alternatives to achieve two different package name per flavor or build type in a library module, and my short answer is: **You can't**, at least without doing something tricky and dirty.

Some guys that recommend using the parameter `applicationIdSuffix` or `applicationId`, that option doesn't work because of the design of library modules restricts those parameters to the app module. In a library, the package **must** be defined in the manifest.

That restriction delimits options to flavors, but, the package attribute in the manifest isn't merged, and you get an error when having different package name for the `scr/main/AndroidManifest.xml` and `src/flavor/AndroidManifest.xml`.

A tricky solution is to get the currently selected flavor form the task name and then change the main manifest in the sourceSets.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile "src/$flavor_name/AndroidManifest.xml"
    }
}
```

This hack works but in general is a bad idea, and I prefer to change the design of my architecture and implement the repository for both Firebase variants in a different way.

Gradle plugin: 3.2.0

Answer (score 1):

**Library projects cannot set applicationId.**

This is the designed behaviour of Android Library project.

> Two different flavors in the library module and set different
>   manifests for each one. The package anyway doesn't change.

Probably you need to change your **Build Variants** to that particular flavor/buildtype then you can see the updated package name taking effect.

See below screenshot.

[image]